# Brian's Death in Final Destination 2

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, final-destination-2

At the very end of *Final Destination 2*, a boy named Brian, who was previously saved from being hit by a truck, dies from an exploding grill. I think the reason he died is that death is correcting its plan, since Brian was supposed to die before. However, I thought the main character drowning and then coming back alive was supposed to prevent all "correctional" deaths. I mean this is the whole reason that the main character and the cop were able to live in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brian was not in the original death list of Route 23. Brian was saved during SUV crash scene so maybe his death has nothing to do with Route 23 death list and that's why he got his end even after they cheated death list.

But also remember one thing we learn from the franchise (spoilers):

> nobody survives

Also from alternate ending of Final Destination 3:

> If Ian is killed normally, the film continues. If Map is selected, an extra scene, where a newspaper blows off of a homeless man who was using it as a blanket, is inserted. It reveals that the survivors of the second film were killed and the viewer is given the option to read the paper and get the details. Kimberly and Thomas were sucked into a faulty wood chipper owned by the farmer of the second film, after they tried to escape a runaway car that was owned by the unlucky lottery winner of the previous film. The death certificate was given by the doctor who was pregnant in the previous film and thought to be the key to surviving death's plan. They had met at the area by coincidence and according to the article, were haunted by the whole incident, with Kimberly dropping out of school and Thomas being sent down to desk duty.

And also in sequels, the same theory proves that

> nobody survives